# Summing a field in an Access table and displaying the total

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

How do I sum a column in Access 2010 and display the total in a new column (using expression builder perhaps)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to store a calculated value in a table. If you need a calculated value, calculate it when you are displaying it. Generally this is done in a report or on a form.

There are exceptions to this, but it sounds like you would be best served by displaying the calculated field in a report/form and not in your table.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(num_fld) as Sum_Nums
FROM your_table
WHERE num_fld > 5;

I don't know about expression builder but this query works

Comment: I want to create a calulated field that displays the totals.

Comment: @YoungUser Where do you want to display the total? ...in a text box on a form or report?

Comment: I would like to diplay the total in each cell on column or/and then I can always bind the table to the respective form or report? This seems to make the most sense to me. Is there a better way? Also, is this possible? It seems like it should be.